# Have I used JSON_decode or php contents incorrectly?

Tags: php, arrays, json, file-get-contents

PHP Version 7.0

So basically there is another website sending information to this script. This script is not connected to any other part of the website. Therefore, I do not view this page. Information is sent in encoded JSON, and I am afraid I am trying to decode this incorrectly, or it's not receiving information properly.

Code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include '../includes/connection.php';
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$UserID = $array['UserID'];
$CallerID = $array['CallerID'];
$Report = $array['Report'];
$Violator = $array['Violator'];
$PlaceLink = $array['PlaceLink'];

if($CallerID !=NULL and $Report != NULL and $PlaceLink != NULL){
    $query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO Calls (`ID`, `UserID`,`CallerID`, `Report`, `Violator`, `PlaceLink`, `Status`) VALUES (NULL, :userID, :CallerID, :Report, :Violator, :PlaceLink, '1')");
    $query->bindParam(':userID', $UserID);
    $query->bindParam(':CallerID', $CallerID);
    $query->bindParam(':Report', $Report);
    $query->bindParam(':Violator', $Violator);
    $query->bindParam(':PlaceLink', $PlaceLink);
    $query->execute();
}
?>
```

Expected Results: The information sent from the other website is inserted into my database under the table "Calls".

Results: Nothing happens.

If I go to the page, there's nothing displayed. This is because there is no HTML at all there for a reason. I don't actually use this as a webpage. I use it as a script.

Comment: Why do you think it's incorrect? Please explain the problem.

Comment: You can see it's supposed to insert the information into a database, which it does not. I know the connection and handler are working as they are used in other places as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Try to echo out the $array or each of the String you want first. Then you will be able to check if it parsed the data correct or wrong. Using print is the way to debug a piece of code when you have doubt about the variable is correct or not.

Comment: Echoing the data will do me no good. I have no way of seeing it as the script is not updating live with the submissions.

Comment: However, I have echoed the information on the sending site, and it is correct.

Comment: Okay i know you are using this as a Server-Side Script which i do also. However, to ensure everything works, it is better to check this using a browser, i mean running this code in a browser rather than php command.

Comment: If you do not want to print it on screen then try to write a Javascript alert function to check if the data parsing in is correct or not

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to do that?

Comment: When I remove the if statement, I get the follow... note, it does this for every variable. Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'CallerID' cannot be null in /home/wattlema/public_html/scripts/addCall.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/wattlema/public_html/scripts/addCall.php(19): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/wattlema/public_html/scripts/addCall.php on line 19

Comment: added echo checking in answer, i know that is not the real answer but no way i can place it in comment. Run in with the folderpath placed in the browser URL. I guess your json file is in local right? if not, try to make one to check if it decodes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include '../includes/connection.php';
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$UserID = $array['UserID'];
$CallerID = $array['CallerID'];
$Report = $array['Report'];
$Violator = $array['Violator'];
$PlaceLink = $array['PlaceLink'];
echo "<script>alert(". $array .");</script>"; 

if($CallerID !=NULL and $Report != NULL and $PlaceLink != NULL){
    $query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO Calls (`ID`, `UserID`,`CallerID`, `Report`, `Violator`, `PlaceLink`, `Status`) VALUES (NULL, :userID, :CallerID, :Report, :Violator, :PlaceLink, '1')");
    $query->bindParam(':userID', $UserID);
    $query->bindParam(':CallerID', $CallerID);
    $query->bindParam(':Report', $Report);
    $query->bindParam(':Violator', $Violator);
    $query->bindParam(':PlaceLink', $PlaceLink);
    $query->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: So I am assuming I need to navigate to the script in my browser, wait, and then send the information and see if the alert comes up?

Comment: if your php is located in "folderpath/index.php", place this in the search box of your browser. With that json data ready. which is (php://input), replace it with sample data if needed

Comment: Alright so basically this is how it works. This script is under /scripts/addCall.php    | On the other website, when a button is pressed, it encodes it's information (gathered by a client) and sends it to this script. To clarify, I go ahead and navigate to this script. While on the page, go ahead and send the data?

Comment: Procedure:
1. Prepare your jsonfile in local path as sample data,and replace "php://input" with that file path. 2. Run this php script in browser to check if the popup shows the correct json array. 3. repeat it with different variable.

Comment: The issue is, I don't exactly know where the information is coming from. It comes from one big domain (example: www.game.com), but may actually be sent from (www.game.com/games/4321512) or (www.game.com/games/1235124)... if that makes sense.

Comment: So how do I need to do this?

Comment: use a local path, which is inside your own computer, and use php to decode that json file

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I know next to nothing about JSON or JSON files.

Comment: uhm okay, you did print sth from sender right? copy that json array and paste inside a txt file, use that txt file path in the decode branket